# Light and object with an array modifier

Tags: modifiers, lighting, parent

I'm trying to make a street and I'm giving it street lamps. I designed one and gave it a bulb with a light inside. I tried to make more along the street using an array modifier, but I can't use it on all three objects. I tried joining them, but you can't join an object with a light. I also made the lamp post a parent and made the bulb and light be children, but the array modifier still didn't work. Also, I'm using Blender 2.93.1.

Comment: Why not just have a separate modifier on each object?  Give each modifier the same count and offset values.  You could even use drivers to see that the 2nd and 3rd objects have modifiers that stay in sync.

Comment: You can put everything in a collection and array a collection instance instead, or use geometry nodes for maximum flexibility